# Layering in iOS (6)

Tags: button, ios6, uiimageview, layer

In my app the user is able to drag a few images, those appear when he presses a button. The problem is that when I drag the UIImageView over the button and release it then I can not touch / drag the image anymore because the button is on top of it though the image is optically over the button.

So: how can I put the button in the background and the image over it?

so this is to create the UIImageView on touch.

```
- (IBAction)SchiffRotButton:(id)sender {  
    NSLog(@"setting schiffrot.png...");  
    [_SchiffRotImageView setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"schiffrot.png"]]; }
```

this is the button itself:

```
UIButton *SchiffRotBuztton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];  
        SchiffRotBuztton.frame = CGRectMake(198, 646, 59, 59);  
        [UIImage imageNamed:@"schifffeldrot.png"];
```

by this i move the image:

```
-(void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{
printf("touch moved \n");
UITouch *myTouch = [touches anyObject];
startPoint = [myTouch locationInView:self.view];
    if ([_whichPiece isEqualToString:@"SchiffGelbImageView"])
{
    _SchiffGelbImageView.center = CGPointMake(startPoint.x, startPoint.y);
}
```

thanks for your help
LiGe

Comment: maybe some code in your question would be better to help you

Comment: i did. can u help? @Math